# How to open the default text editor in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, text, editor, default

I need to open the default text editor in Linux without having a file. I know that I could use the command [xdg-open](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/User:Larivact/xdg-open) to open a file in the default editor, but I need to open the editor without having a file and let the user create the file.

---

I solved it with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/share/applications/
atalho=`grep $1 defaults.list | tail -1 | sed "s:^$1=::" `
`grep '^Exec' $atalho | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//'` &
```

It works fine on Ubuntu, but I'm worried if this script will work in other Linux distributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no completely reliable concept of "default editor" on Linux, let alone more broadly Unix-like systems.

Traditionally, users would set the environment variable `EDITOR` to the path of their editor of choice. If this variable is set, I'm thinking you can be reasonably confident that they will know how to use it, even if they end up in something horrible like `nano`.

A slightly newer convention is to set `VISUAL` to the preferred "visual editor" - I guess the terminology comes from `vi` to contrast against line editors like `ed`.

```
${VISUAL-${EDITOR-nano}} path/to/new/file.txt
```

On Debianish systems, the system default editor is configurable via `alternatives` and available simply with the command `editor`.

On XDG systems, of course, you could simply

```
touch path/to/new/file.txt
xdg-open path/to/new/file.txt
```

Needless to say, this only works if you have XDG, i.e. In practice a Linux (or maybe modern *BSD) platform with an active graphical session (excludes Mac and pre-XDG graphical systems as well as of course any server environment where there is no GUI).

As an aside, if I can guess even roughly what your script does, it could probably be pared down to a fairly simple `sed` script. Remember, `sed` can do (almost) everything `grep` and `tail` can. Maybe see also [Combining two sed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands) - here is a quick and dirty refactoring.

```
cd /usr/share/applications
$(sed -n "s:^Exec=\([^%]*\)\(%.\(.*\)\)*:\1\3:p" "$(sed -n "s:^$1=::p" defaults.list | tail -1)" | tail -1) &
```

However, from quick googling, it looks like `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` is specific to  OpenDesktop environments; but it's the system-wide default default - the admin could have installed an override in a different location, and individual users probably have individual preferences on top of that. Finding and traversing this hierarchy is precisely what `xdg-open` does, so I'm not going to try to reimplement it in an ad-hoc script of my own, and suggest you shouldn't, either.

There is nothing about graphical environments in your question, so it's unclear whether you are actually looking for a simple editor for beginners who barely know how to click and drool in a graphical environment (in which case I'd say go with `touch` followed by `xdg-open`) or a competent programmers' editor which way or may not run in a window (maybe try `VISUAL` with fallback to `EDITOR`, and document that you use this mechanism).

Comment: Maybe see also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications which is specific to Arch Linux but very solid. Large parts of it are generally applicable.

Answer (score 1):

If [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) is your default editor, I would do something like "vi mynewfile.txt".

Comment: Forgot to mention this reference guide: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html