# How to invoke "EDITOR" environment variable to open/edit file, in a secure way?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, editor

Is there a way to use the EDITOR or VISUAL environment variables in a bash script to edit a given file using the editor of the users choice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open the default text editor in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252791/how-to-open-the-default-text-editor-in-linux)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshell%5D+EDITOR+VISUAL+environment+variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}} "${filename}"
```

This will use the `VISUAL` variable if it's set, otherwise `EDITOR`, and if neither is set it will fallback to `vi`.

You can use a different fallback if you like. In particular, Debian-based distros typically ship a [binary named `editor`](https://wiki.debian.org/TextEditor#How_to_set_a_default_text_editor) that system administrators can control to set a system-wide default editor as a fallback...

`vi` is typically ubiquitous, so it's probably an appropriate default to use.

Note that the variables are unquoted here. This is unfortunately necessary, since an `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` setting can include command arguments, so supporting *word splitting* is required.

For example, one might use `EDITOR="emacs -nw"` to force the use of Emacs on the terminal (rather than the window system), or `EDITOR="vim -u $HOME/.vim/custom-vimrc"` to have Vim use a custom configuration when launched by external programs.

**UPDATE:** Reversed the order to try `$VISUAL` first, then `$EDITOR`, since that seems to be the most common setup (e.g. Mutt mail client, git, etc.)

Comment: Would it be recommended to try VISUAL first? As a developer, what are your expectations?

Comment: @wesm https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4859/281844 but I've seen programs that try `$EDITOR` first as well. I guess these days it's rare to have `$VISUAL` even set... And when it is, it's usually set to the same as `$EDITOR`.

Comment: @wesm Actually, just reversed the order in my answer. Now thinking about it, `$VISUAL` first makes more sense. Also, it's what both `mutt` and `git` do, so I'll trust what the authors of those tools decided to use. 

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the validation.

Comment: On zsh, include a `=` to turn on word splitting: `${=VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}`