# Solaris sed label too long

Tags: sed

I am trying to execute a shell file, in which there is a line:

```
sed -ne ':1;/PinnInstitutionPath/{n;p;b1}' Institution | sed -e s/\ //g | sed -e s/\=//g | sed -e s/\;//g | sed -e s/\"//g | sed -e s/\Name//g
```

And un error message turns out : `"Label too long:      :1;/PinnInstitutionPath/{n;p;b1}"`

I am a noob at linux, so can anyone help me to solve this problem, thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what does Institution look like? In general, 'sed' is a scripting language so you can use only one sed with statements separated by semicolons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7657662/2327328

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
sed -ne ':1;/PinnInstitutionPath/{n;p;b1}'
```

to

```
sed -ne ':1' -e '/PinnInstitutionPath/{n;p;b1}'
```

Also, you don't need to call `sed` so many times:

```
sed -ne 's/[ =;"]//g; s/Name//g' -e ':1' -e '/PinnInstitutionPath/{n;p;b1}'
```

Comment: Thank you! It works fine, to notice that it truns out another error message "Too many {'s", again i dont know why...can i ignore it?

Comment: @user2889802 I'm not sure, first of all check the command, maybe you forgot the closing `}`?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning 'sed: Label too long' in Solaris (SunOS) - you will need to split your command into several lines, if you use labels.
In your case

```
sed -ne ':1
    /PinnInstitutionPath/{
    n
    p
    b 1
    }' Institution | sed -e s/\ //g -e s/\=//g -e s/\;//g -e s/\"//g -e s/\Name//g
```