# Sed command not working in sun solaris machine

Tags: sed, sunos

I have an xml file in which I am searching for the below pattern.

```
<ServiceConfig Id="554">
<Comment>ECS_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7.32251@3gpp.org</Comment>
<MaxCost>0.000000</MaxCost>
<MaxCostLocalCurrency>true</MaxCostLocalCurrency>
<Atomic>false</Atomic>
<TariffSwitchHandling>external</TariffSwitchHandling>
<CdrAtTollFreeService>false</CdrAtTollFreeService>
<BonusDuringSession>false</BonusDuringSession>
<UserMessagesStartOfSession>true</UserMessagesStartOfSession>
<UserMessagesDuringSession>true</UserMessagesDuringSession>
<UseAccumulatorStartValues>false</UseAccumulatorStartValues>
<ValidityTime Factor="1">120</ValidityTime>
<Volume>
<Total PreferredFactor="1024" Preferred="500" MinimumFactor="1000000" Minimum="0"></Total>
</Volume>
<VolumeQuotaThreshold Factor="1">0</VolumeQuotaThreshold>
<SendQuotaHoldingTime>false</SendQuotaHoldingTime>
<QuotaHoldingTime Factor="1">0</QuotaHoldingTime>
<SendQuotaConsumptionTime>false</SendQuotaConsumptionTime>
<QuotaConsumptionTime Factor="1">0</QuotaConsumptionTime>
</ServiceConfig>
```

Block having open & close tags as "ServiceConfig" & in which comment tag has the "ECS_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7" string. for this purpose I used the below sed command.

```
sed -n '/<ServiceConfig Id=/ { :a /<\/ServiceConfig/! { N; ba; }; /<Comment>ECS_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7./ { p; b; }; }' ServiceConfig.xml
```

This command is working perfectly on linux system but failing on sunOS with below error.

```
Label too long: /<ServiceConfig Id=/ { :a /<\/ServiceConfig/! { N; ba; }; /<Comment>ECS_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7./ { p; b; }; }
```

I am not able to understand what is the cause of this trouble.

Comment: Version of sed are you using?

Comment: Which OS version do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solaris sed label too long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840661/solaris-sed-label-too-long)

Comment: @Cyrus & 999 : I am working on 5.10 sunOS with default sed.
Yes I went through the other question but could find any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solaris (most often by default setting and/of sed version), `;` are not interpreted as new line like on GNU sed, use real new line especialy for label and jump

```
sed -n '/<ServiceConfig Id=/ {
:a
  /<\/ServiceConfig/ !{ 
     N
     ba
     }
  /<Comment>ECS_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7./ { 
     p
     b
     }
  }' ServiceConfig.xml
```

or use several `-e` action parameter

```
sed -n -e '/<ServiceConfig Id=/ {' -e ':a' -e '/<\/ServiceConfig/ !{ N; ba' -e '}; /<Comment>ECS_OCS_V1_0.0.0.7./ { p; b' -e'}' -e '}' ServiceConfig.xml
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for response..This command is given error "Unrecognized command: /<\/ServiceConfig/! { N; ba "

Comment: I forget this, space is before a `!` not after. i change in my reply

Comment: sorry for trouble but now its giving  "too many }'s"  error.. even though count of braces are matching... :(

Comment: Retry with only 1 instruction per line (reply adapted)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: Your last version works without errors with non GNU sed (/usr/bin/sed) from Solaris 11.

Comment: This is working perfectly.. thanks a lot for your time & effort.. :)