# Combine statements in Sed

Tags: sed

I have over 1000 text files where I need to remove the first 6 lines and also remove some boilerplate text from the bottom of each file.

I am trying this in one command in sed, if possible.

**Here are the individual commands**

```
sed -i.bak '/Some text as starting delimiter/,/Some text as an ending delimiter/d' My-File.txt

sed -e '1,6d' < MyFile.txt
```

Can these be combined ?

How so?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining two sed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i.bak -e '/Some text as starting delimiter/,/Some text as an ending delimiter/d' -e '1,6d' My-File.txt
```

or

```
sed -i.bak '/Some text as starting delimiter/,/Some text as an ending delimiter/d;1,6d' My-File.txt
```