# When I run a python code, it says “<< was unexpected at this time"

Tags: python, linux, sed

Basically, it's a python code from our collaborator that used to generate mesh, which is developed under Linux environment. I use Cygwin to run this code on windows. The trouble part is as follows. BiV_temp.geo is also a python script. So the command is to substitute the string <> in the script BiV_temp.geo with a predefined number and the file names.

```
os.system('cp BiV_fiber.geo BiV_temp.geo')
cmd = "sed -i 's/<<Meshsize>>/"+"%5.2f"%(meshsize)+"/g' BiV_temp.geo"
os.system(cmd)
cmd = "sed -i 's/<<LVfilename>>/"+"\"%s\""%(LVendocutfilename)+"/g' BiV_temp.geo"
os.system(cmd)
cmd = "sed -i 's/<<RVfilename>>/"+"\"%s\""%(RVendocutfilename)+"/g' BiV_temp.geo"
os.system(cmd)
cmd = "sed -i 's/<<Epifilename>>/"+"\"%s\""%(epicutfilename)+"/g' BiV_temp.geo"
os.system(cmd)
cmd = "gmsh -3 BiV_temp.geo -o %s"%(mshfilename)
os.system(cmd)
cmd = "rm BiV_temp.geo"
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Are you sure it was a Python traceback, and not a sed error? I've never seen an error message like that.

Comment: Probably. As I am all new to python and unix, so it may be the sed error...

Comment: @H.Zou Please paste your attempt at running the script and the ensuing error to your question so we can be sure.

Comment: Try `print("sed -i 's/<<Meshsize>>/"+"%5.2f"%(meshsize)+"/g' BiV_temp.geo")`, exit python, then paste the result on the command line. This works for me with a dummy file using bash on linux mint, but maybe it angers your shell or your `sed`. You could replace `sed` with `echo` to see if you have the same problem.

Comment: You don't tell which line causes the error (there are multiple lines with `<<`). You also don't provide the input file for other people to attempt, or (preferably) a small input file that still causes your error. That makes it a lot harder to help you with.

Comment: @tdelaney The command can be executed seperately on the command line. With replacing sed with echo it doesn't help. So not sure why in python script it can not work.

Comment: @Evert All the << cause this error.

Comment: This is crazy.  If your entire program consists of shell script, write a shell script, not a Python wrapper to start a new shell for each piece of shell script.  Also notice that `sed` is a scripting language, so you can [combine all of these `sed` snippets into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands); then copying the source file to a temporary file and doing inline substitutions `-i` no longer makes any sense (if it ever did).

Comment: You can possibly execute it fine in your terminal, because `os.system()` does not equal your terminal. Shell, envvars etc are different (just run e.g. `os.system('echo $0')` and `os.system('env')` from a Python prompt). Possibly, that could cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The sane solution is for your "collaborator" to write Python code which allows you to pass in these things as parameters to a function call.

Answer (score -1):

you are trying to executing command code in python? 
and i notice in `"%5.2f"%(meshsize)` you wrote `%5`, for adding text you should add `%s`and also avoid putting plus sign, it make it really hard to read and messy, i would write all in one line like this:

```
meshsize = 100
cmd = "sed -i 's/<<Meshsize>>/%s5.2f/g' BiV_temp.geo" %meshsize
print cmd
```

if your `meshsize` is a list of x,y,z then write it like this:

```
meshsize = (100,50,20)
cmd = "sed -i 's/<<Meshsize>>/%s,%s,%s5.2f/g' BiV_temp.geo" %meshsize
print cmd
```

hope that help.

Comment: This is just a comment about style, it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Which "you" do you mean? He is trying to replace "<<Meshsize>>" with a floating point number using `sed`. He doesn't need the `%s` stuff you are doing in your second incorrect example.

Comment: @tdelaney: it make it readable, which is cunsider one of the problems, so people wont skip reading it, you type your code in notepad don't you? :D

Comment: @tdelaney when i read the question it was only 2 lines of code, but nothing else, so i just suggest to write as such way. what's wrong with you?

Comment: Hi guys, don't be angry. All the suggestions are appreciated. @BernardRouhi

Comment: @H.Zou yeah, i actually never knew `%5.2f` exist, i usually add as String `%s` and number as `%d`, even that everything will be string in `cmd` variable anyway, but that was something for me to take.

Comment: What do you mean, what's wrong with me? This isn't an answer and is incorrect to boot. Low quality answers get dinged... get used to it.