# Linux, find replace on a folder of files using a list of items for replacement?

Tags: sed

I'm looking for a way to use an external list (Replace.txt) to replace text  on a folder of 50 files in /temp.

My replacement file Replace.txt will be something like the following but contain 400+ items.

```
Old,New
Apples, Oranges
Mellon, Bananas
Car, Train
```

e.g.

I could use sed but adding my list manually would not be efficient. I don't know if you can use an external file list with similar code for sed.

Code:

```
sed -i 's/item1/itemb/g:s/itemc/itemd/g:s/iteme/itemf/g' *
```

Anyone have anything useful?

Comment: This is common and easy enough.  Google for `sed -f -`.

Comment: Incidentally, `sed` commands are separated by newline or semicolon, not colon.

Comment: Since I'm not that familiar with sed I'm struggling to find the correct syntax. I have googled for an answer before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily generate a `sed` script from your input file ... using `sed`.

```
sed 's/^/s%/;s/, */%/;s/$/%g/' Replace.txt | sed -f - -i /directory/*
```

The first command in the pipeline generates a `sed` script from your replacement patterns; it looks like

```
s%Old%New%g
s%Apples%Bananas%g
```

and we then feed this to another `sed` instance, specifying standard input (`-`) as the file to read the script from (`-f`) and the files you want to perform these replacements in as the file name arguments.

`s/^/s%/` inserts `s%` at beginning of line.  `s/, */%/` replaces the first comma (with optional trailing whitespace) with just `%`.  `s/$/%g/` adds `%g` at the end of each line.  (In regex, `^` matches the beginning of line, and `$` matches the end of line.)

Linux `sed` happily reads a script from standard input; some other platforms may be encumbered, or require a workaround like `/dev/stdin` instead of `-` as the file name argument.  In the worst case, save the generated script in a temporary file, then remove it when you're done.

Perhaps notice that this will happily replace `PineApplesauce` with `PineBananasauce` and `BOldface` with `BNewface`. You can perhaps devise a more constrained regular expression around the `Old` text. Notice also that if `Old` contains regular expression metacharacters, those should be escaped if you want `sed` to replace them literally; so

```
s%your *new* friend%your *old* buddy%
```

is wrong, and should instead be something like

```
s%your [*]new[*] friend%your *old* buddy%
```

if the intent is to interpret the "old" phrase as literal text.

Comment: That's brilliant!

I just ran a sample and there is a problem with the output of the replace item it appears to have doubled up the 1st character.

OOranges
BBananas
TTrain

Comment: I cannot replace that here.  I imagine you will have transcribed the script incorrectly somehow; or maybe your real data contains regex special characters unlike the apples and oranges example you provided.

Comment: User error on the doubling up issue, the initial list was incorrect. Many thanks for your assistance!