# Why does outer while loop in Bash not finishing?

Tags: bash

I don't understand why this outer loop exits just because the inner loop can finish.

The `$1` refers to a file with a lot of pattern/replacement lines. The `$2` is a list of words. The problem is that the outer loop exits already after the first pattern/replacement line. I want it to exit after all the lines in `$1` are read.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Receive SED SCRIPT WORDLIST 

if [ -f temp.txt ];
then 
    > temp.txt
else
    touch temp.txt
fi

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
    echo -e "s/$line/p" >> temp.txt

    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
    do
        sed -nf temp.txt $2
    done
        > temp.txt
done < $1
```

Comment: You don't need this `bash` and `sed` combination to make this work. Just give us the required input and output expected

Comment: Also it is not clear what error behavior the current script is producing.

Comment: A second `read` call on a same input stream would read the second line and would not be as what you intended to do

Comment: Thanks Inian, the solution was inspired by your last comment. I actually don't need the second while loop :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.  If you are trying to read a bunch of patterns from a file and use them to perform substitutions in another file, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253663/linux-find-replace-on-a-folder-of-files-using-a-list-of-items-for-replacement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want calculate de sed expressions and write it on a file, and then apply this expresions to other file.

This is so much easier than your are doing it.

First of all, you dont need to check if *temp.txt* already exists. When you redirect the output of a command to a file, if this file do not exist, it will be created. But if you want to reset the file, I recommend you to use *truncate* command.

In the body of the script, I don't understand why you put a second while loop to read from a file, but you don't put a file to read.

I think that you need is something like this:

```
truncate -s 0 sed_expressions.txt

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo -e "s/$line/p" >> sed_expressions.txt
done < $1
sed -nf sed_expressions.txt $2 > out_file.txt
```

Try it and tell me if is this that you need.

Bye!

Comment: Thanks A, I reached the same conclusion regarding the 2nd while loop. I haven't learned the truncate command before so thank you for sharing. This looks much more efficient.

Comment: I'm glad. If this is all you need, please mark my answer as correct to close this question.