# Execute shell command line by line from a file

Tags: shell, sed

I have a .txt file which has sed replace commands on each line and has 1000+ entries. The file is on my server.
Can any one please help me how to run the commands in file line by line and execute till the end of file.

My txt file looks like

```
sed -i 's|http://www.myoldsite/url/category/another/blah|http://www.mynewsite.com|g' ./db.sql
sed -i 's|http://www.myoldsite/url/category/blah/blah|http://www.mynewsite.com|g' ./db.sql
sed -i 's|http://www.myoldsite/url/category/blah|http://www.mynewsite.com|g' ./db.sql
```

Comment: Add execute permission to the file, `chmod +x file`, add a `bash` interpreter `#!/bin/bash` (optional but recommended) and run as `./file`

Comment: sorry can you make it more understandable

Comment: @Inian Make that `#!/bin/sh` - you don't know if there is a bash on the OP's system. Not all the world's a Linux system.

Comment: what about `sh my-txt-file` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple sed search/replace command for urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480920/multiple-sed-search-replace-command-for-urls)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combining 2 sed commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your file to a list of substitution commands by removing all occurrences of `sed -i '` and `' ./db.sql`.

Using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), the list can then be processed as a file passed to the sed `-f` option.

```
sed -i -f <(sed "s/[^']*'//;s/'.*//" file) ./db.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this one helps:

```
for i in $(cat yourfile.txt)
do
    sudo $i
done
```

**EDIT:**

Why downvote?

There are multiple solutions to your problem.

**SOLUTION 1**

Running each command in your .txt file:

Make your .txt file executable by giving command:

```
chmod +x yourfile.txt
```

And then executing it by giving a command:

```
./yourfile.txt
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Creating a script

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=$1
while read line; do
     $line
done < $FILE
```

making the script executable:

```
chmod +x yourscriptfile.sh
```

And then executing your script by providing your .txt file as argument:

```
./yourscriptfile.sh yourfilewithcommands.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: just run this on shell window ?

Comment: No this is the loop that runs each command in your .txt file.
I Assume that you don't want to edit your .txt file in any way. To achieve what you're looking for you should create a script that contains this loop. And then execute this script.
If you need more explanations just let me know :)

Comment: How to create script

Comment: solution 1 gives no such file or directory :(

Comment: are you in the same directory as your .txt file?

Comment: changed the txt file to unix format and ran the command,Now we got this, first line in txt "sed -i `s|http://www.myoldsite/url/category/blah?pagetype=brand&amp;prefn1=brand&amp;prefv1=adidas|http:///www.mynewsite.com|g` ./db.sql" we got this error : error ./links.txt: line 1: s: command not found
./links.txt: line 1: amp: command not found
./links.txt: line 1: http://www.myoldsite/url/category/blah?pagetype=brand: No such file or directory
./links.txt: line 1: amp: command not found
./links.txt: line 1: http:///www.mynewsite.com: No such file or directory

Comment: Do your sed commands work correctly if you run them in terminal separately? In my examples I used ln -lah and echo commands for testing purposes not sed command.

Comment: @Melvin
I tried solution 1 and with exact same sed commands and for me it worked OK.
What OS do you have? I'm running Debian GNU/LInux 8 (jessie)
Command for checking your OS: cat /etc/*-release

Comment: Debian 14.04 ubuntu

Comment: @Melvin
I tried different EOL conversions in my .txt files and this is what i found out:
Windows format caused "no such file or directory"
Unix/OSX format: EVERYTHING OK
Old Mac format: got same error as you.

So your .txt file should have correct EOL format. I am using notepad++ for correct formatting: Edit -> EOL Conversions.

Answer (score -1):

You can turn the file into a script by adding

```
#!/bin/sh
```

as the first line, than making the file executable with

```
chomd u+x file
```

and then just run it with

```
./file
```

BUT, this will be very slow. It's much faster to run `sed` only once with all the expressions, i.e. changing it into

```
sed -i~ 's|http://www.myoldsite/url/category/another/blah|http://www.mynewsite.com|g;
         s|http://www.myoldsite/url/category/blah/blah|http://www.mynewsite.com|g;
         s|http://www.myoldsite/url/category/blah|http://www.mynewsite.com|g
' ./db.sql
```

Comment: the arguments should be in each line ?

Comment: @Melvin: It's not important, but they can. It might be easier for you to format the script in this way.