# how to replace spaces with underscore and doublequotes with nothing in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have the string as follows:

```
$ echo "$val1"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
```

Now I can use this method to replace the spaces with underscores

```
$ echo "NAME_"${val1// /_}"_NAME"
NAME_"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"_NAME
```

And can do the same for replacing `"` double quotes with nothing

```
$ echo "NAME_"${val1//'"'/}"_NAME"
NAME_$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB_NAME
```

Now I can use sed to do the same - to replace the spaces with underscores

```
$ echo "$val1" | sed s/" "/_/g
"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"
```

And I can then remove the double quotes by adding this `sed s/'"'/''/g`

```
$ echo "$val1" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g
$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB
```

So this is what I want (spaces repalaced with underscore and double quotes removed) but can i achieve it using my first approach above e.g.

```
$ echo "NAME_"${val1// /_}"_NAME"
NAME_"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"_NAME
```

This is my attempt

```
$ echo "NAME_"${${val1// /_//'"'/}}"_NAME"
-sh: "NAME_"${${val1// /_//'"'/}}"_NAME": bad substitution
```

**edit1** this is the sed I can achieve but I want to be able to achieve this by my first approach

```
$ echo "NAME_"$val1"_NAME" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g
NAME_$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB_NAME
```

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38559775/2392358) `a="NAME_${${val1// /_}//\"/}_NAME"` can be done in zsh

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to nest string manipulation operations on a variable because the first parameter in the `${var/sub/rep}` is a variable name, not a string.

```
NAME='"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"'
NAME=${NAME// /_}
NAME=${NAME//\"/}
```

Coincidentally, `sed` is a scripting language; you can trivially perform multiple substitutions in one script.  See [combining 2 sed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't. Also, the quoting is wrong in all of your commands:

Wrong:

```
$ echo "NAME_"${val1// /_}"_NAME"
NAME_"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"_NAME
```

Right:

```
$ echo "NAME_${val1// /_}_NAME"
NAME_"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"_NAME
```

Wrong:

```
$ echo "NAME_"${val1//'"'/}"_NAME"
NAME_$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB_NAME
```

Right:

```
$ echo "NAME_${val1//\"/}_NAME"
NAME_$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB_NAME
```

Wrong:

```
$ echo "$val1" | sed s/" "/_/g
"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"
```

Right:

```
$ echo "$val1" | sed 's/ /_/g'
"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"
```

Wrong:

```
$ echo "$val1" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g
$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB
```

Right:

```
$ echo "$val1" | sed 's/ /_/g; s/"//g'
$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB
```

Wrong:

```
$ echo "NAME_"${val1// /_}"_NAME"
NAME_"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"_NAME
```

Right:

```
$ echo "NAME_${val1// /_}_NAME"
NAME_"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"_NAME
```

Wrong:

```
$ echo "NAME_"${${val1// /_//'"'/}}"_NAME"
-sh: "NAME_"${${val1// /_//'"'/}}"_NAME": bad substitution
```

Right:

```
There is no right way to write that.
```

Wrong:

```
$ echo "NAME_"$val1"_NAME" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g
NAME_$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB_NAME
```

Right:

```
$ echo "NAME_${val1}_NAME" | sed 's/ /_/g; s/"//g'
NAME_$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB_NAME
```

See if you can find a tutorial on shell quoting before it bites you.

Comment: when you say wrong, specifically in your first wrong/right, do you mean bad syntax? I accept your point with the quotes in `sed` this looks better, `echo "$val1" | sed 's/ /_/g'`, but it does give the same result. maybe you could brifly comment.tks

Comment: I mean potentially dangerous and will fail in weird and wonderful ways given various values of the shell variable and/or the directory you execute the command from and/or your environment settings. Google something like "always quote shell variables" to see articles like http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/133219 that discuss the issue.