# Write to a file + filename is a string that needs to be manipulated slightly

Tags: string, file, output, filenames

This is a string I want to manipulate and be part of a filename I want to write to:

```
$ echo "$val1"
"$29.95 Carryover Plan 1GB"
```

This is what I want the file name to be, (spaces repalaced with underscore and double quotes removed) and `NAME_` added at start and `_NAME` added at end.

```
$ echo "NAME_"$val1"_NAME" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g
NAME_$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB_NAME
```

And this is me trying to write test  data to the file in question

```
$ a="NAME_"$val1"_NAME" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g && echo "test123" > "$a"
```

But it does not come out as I want `"$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"`

```
$ ls -lth
total 44M
-rw-r--r-- 1 kevin.smith mkpasswd    8 Jul 25 16:08 "$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB"
```

**How can I write to the file and for the file name to be** `NAME_$29.95_Carryover_Plan_1GB_NAME`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a="NAME_"$val1"_NAME" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g
```

doesn't do what I expect you wanted it to. You'll need to actually `echo` the variable:

```
a="$(echo "NAME_"$val1"_NAME" | sed s/" "/_/g | sed s/'"'/''/g)"
```

Or a bit nicer (IMO):

```
a="$(echo "NAME_${val1}_NAME" | sed 's/ /_/g;s/"//g')"
```

Or if you're running zsh rather than bash:

```
a="NAME_${${val1// /_}//\"/}_NAME"
```

Comment: `$ a="NAME_${${val1// /_}//\"/}_NAME"
-sh: NAME_${${val1// /_}//\"/}_NAME: bad substitution` that is a q i asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559463/how-to-replace-spaces-with-underscore-and-doublequotes-with-nothing-in-bash/38561193#38561193) and was told it could not be done. Can you explain why I am getting `bad substitution`?

Comment: I forgot to note this doesn't work in bash. Fixed now.