# SED: converting JSDOC's @link into Markdown [links](...)

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Disclaimer: I got as far as:

```
cat GUIDE.md  | sed 's/{@link \([^#]*\)#\([^ ]*\)}/[\1#\2](https:\/\/mercmobily.github.io\/best-webdriver\/\1#\2/g'  | less
```

So, it's *nearly* functional.

I have a GUIDE.md file which is in pure markdown, but it includes JSDOC links.

I need to scan the GUIDE.md file and change these:

```
Remember that in {@link Browser#setAlwaysMatchKey AlwaysMatch} or {@link Browser#setRootKey}  (all of the {@link Browser Browser} class), you must try [...]
```

Into:

```
Remember that in [AlwaysMatch](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/Browser#setAlwaysMatchKey) or [Browser#setRootKey](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/Browser#setRootKey) (all of the [Browser](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/Browser) class), you must try [...]
```

So basically:

```
{@link Class#method Description}
->
[Description](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/Class.html#method)

{@link Class#method}
->
[Class#method](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/Class.html#method)
```

Where #method is optional, so:

```
{@link Class Description}
->
[Description](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/Class.html)

{@link Class}
->
[Class](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/Class.html)
```

At this point, I got up to:

```
cat GUIDE.md  | sed 's/{@link \([^#]*\)#\([^ ]*\)}/[\1#\2](https:\/\/mercmobily.github.io\/best-webdriver\/\1#\2/g'  | less
```

However:

- The `#method` is not optional: it must be there. How do I make it non-mandatory?
- The description is not considered at all. This is tricky, and I wonder if one SED regexp can do this. Basically, the input can be `{@link Class#method blah blah}` (the link text should be `blah blah` or `{@link Class#method}` (the link text should be `Class#method`)

If making one regexp that includes the optional regexp is too difficult, I will have to pass the file through sed twice.

Ideas?

Comment: No, you don't have to pass the file through `sed` twice. `sed` is a scripting language; you can specify as many commands as you like in a single `sed` script. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands

Comment: You'll probably also want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: Wouldn't simply taking the first token after @link into the link work? `'s/{@link \([^ }]*\) \([^}]*\)}/[\1](\2)/g'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with the two following sed substitutions (can be separated with newline or `;` or multiple `-e` expressions), don't know how to do it with one in sed:

```
sed  '
s/{@link \([^} #]*\)\(#[^} #]*\)\? \([^} ]*\)}/[\3](https:\/\/mercmobily.github.io\/best-webdriver\/\1.html\2)/g
s/{@link \([^} #]*\)\(#[^} #]*\)\?}/[\1\2](https:\/\/mercmobily.github.io\/best-webdriver\/\1.html\2)/g
' << 'END'
{@link Class#method Description}
{@link Class#method}
{@link Class Description}
{@link Class}
END
```

Note to avoid to escape `/` another delimiter can be used `,` for example:

```
sed  '
s,{@link \([^} #]*\)\(#[^} #]*\)\? \([^} ]*\)},[\3](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/\1.html\2),g
s,{@link \([^} #]*\)\(#[^} #]*\)\?},[\1\2](https://mercmobily.github.io/best-webdriver/\1.html\2),g
' << 'END'
{@link Class#method Description}
{@link Class#method}
{@link Class Description}
{@link Class}
END
```

Otherwise with perl can be done in one

```
perl -pe 's/\{\@link ([^} #]*)(#[^} #]*)?(?: ([^} ]*))?\}/"[".($3?$3:$1.$2)."](https:\/\/mercmobily.github.io\/best-webdriver\/$1.html$2)"/ge' << 'END'
{@link Class#method Description}
{@link Class#method}
{@link Class Description}
{@link Class}
END
```

Note that expression `($3?$3:$1.$2)` can be shortened `($3||$1.$2)`