# Combine sed commands into one command in bash script

Tags: bash, sed, jq

I'd like to improve this line:

```
aws_iam_role=$(aws iam get-role --role-name rl-company-admin --profile=company-bill |
jq -r '.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS' |
sed "s/arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user\///g" |
grep tdunphy |
sed 's/"//g'|
sed 's/,//g')
```

This is the raw output of the command with no processing:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name rl-company-admin --profile=company-bill
{
    "Role": {
        "Description": "company Admin Role", 
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17", 
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
                    "Effect": "Allow", 
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": [
                            "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/tdunphy", 
                            "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/user1", 
                            "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/user2", 
                            "arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/user3", 
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "MaxSessionDuration": 3600, 
        "RoleId": "AROAJGNAT3IXV7DIWSDCK", 
        "CreateDate": "2018-01-18T17:35:27Z", 
        "RoleName": "rl-company-admin", 
        "Path": "/", 
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::188087670762:role/rl-company-admin"
    }
}
```

How can I use one sed statement to process this text instead of using multiple sed statements?

Comment: For efficiency, do the `grep tdunphy` before the `sed` calls. You can also change `sed 's/"//g'| sed 's/,//g'` to `sed 's/[,"]//g'`.

Comment: You could also get it down to one `sed` using the `-r` option: `sed -r 's/arn:aws:iam::832839043616:user\/|,|"//g'`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands; in brief, `sed "s/[\"']//g"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done in **single `jq`** command like this this avoiding invoking multiple external commands e.g. `grep`, `sed` etc:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name rl-company-admin --profile=company-bill |
jq --arg u 'tdunphy' -r '
 .Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS[] |
 select(. | endswith($u)) | sub("arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/"; "")'
```

**Output:**

```
tdunphy
```

Comment: `endswith()` instead of `contains()` maybe?

Comment: Yes definitely `endswith` will be better here, I just translated `grep` :) but fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great solution. However I do need to 'sed' out that last part: `arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/`. This is the command I'm using:`aws iam get-role --role-name "$aws_role_name" --profile="$aws_key" | jq --arg u "tdunphy" -r '.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS[] | select(. | endswith($u))' | sed "s/arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user\///g"`

Comment: Oh ok that can also be handled in `jq` but won't that gave same string as what you pass in `$u` i.e. `tdumphy`

Comment: Without `sed` you can do: `jq --arg u 'tdunphy' -r '
.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS[] |
select(. | endswith($u)) | sub("arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/"; "")'`

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to, this combines the functionality of all your `sed` and `grep` lines:

```
sed -n 's/arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user\///g; s/[,"]//g; /tdunphy/ {p}'
```

Whether that counts as an improvement is somewhat in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 3):

Change your call to `jq` to look like this and then you don't have to strip the other characters:

```
jq -r '.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS[]'
                                                               ^^ Add these
```

You could try this also:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name rl-company-admin --profile=company-bill | \
  jq -r '.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS[] | split("/") | last' | \
  grep tdunphy
```

This might be a bit terse, but you can do it all with one `jq` call:

```
jq -r '[.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS[] | split("/") | last] | map(select(. == "tdunphy"))[]'
```

Comment: THANKS! That does get me most of the way there. I still need to strip this bit, however:`arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user/`. This line seems to do it with less sed: `aws iam get-role --role-name rl-ksr --profile=company-bill | jq -r '.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS[]'  | grep tdunphy | sed "s/arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user\///g"  | grep tdunphy`

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
sed 's/[,"]//g'
```

instead of two seds (if that's even a word)

Comment: Or `tr -d ',"'`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
sed "s/arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user\///g" |
grep tdunphy |
sed 's/"//g'|
sed 's/,//g'
```

with

```
sed -n '/tdunphy/ {
        s/arn:aws:iam::123456789101:user\///g
        s/[,"]//g
        p
     '
```