# execute multiple commands on the same match in sed

Tags: regex, sed

I know I can run commands against a match in `sed` like so:

```
$ cat file
line1
line2
line3
line4

$ sed -e "/^line2/ s/^/# /" file
line1
# line2
line3
line4
```

Is it possible to run multiple commands, say `s/^/#/` and `s/$/ # invalid/` on the same match?

I tried adding them both but I get an error:

```
$ sed -e "/^line2/ s/^/# / s/$/ # /" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'
```

I tried using `;` but that seems to discard the initial match and execute on every line in the input:

```
$ sed -e "/^line2/ s/^/# / ; s/$/ # /" file
line1 #
# line2 #
line3 #
line4 #
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining two sed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands)

Comment: @Tiw I am sorry, I should have put in the question that I tried `{}` blocks but could not get it to work. However, I now realize what I was doing wrong and got it working with: `sed -e "/^line2/ { s/^/# / ; s/$/ # asdf/ }" file`.

Comment: @tripleee It is a duplicate in that they both want to combine commands but mine is unique in that I wanted to match a pattern then apply commands like `s///` or `a TEXT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** In case you are looking very specifically to execute multiple statements when a condition has met then you could use `{..}` block statements as follows.(Just saw @Tiw suggested same thing in comments too.)

```
sed '/^line2/ {s/^/#/; s/$/ # invalid/}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution with `sed` here. (I am simply taking line 
 which is starting with `line2` in a memory buffer `\1` then simply while putting substituted/new_value adding `#` before it and appending `# invalid` after it)

```
sed '/^line2/s/\(.*\)/# \1 # invalid/'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
sed "/^line2/ s/^/# /;/^line2/s/$/ # invalid/"  Input_file
```

What is happening in your attempt, you are simply doing substitution which is happening on each line irrespective of either it starts from `line2` or not, so when you give that condition before substitution it should work then.

Comment: Yes this works but I'm looking for a way to do it within the same match block.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, please try my EDIT solution now and let me know?

Comment: Thank you. I was putting the `{}` in the wrong place. This works!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with extended regexp:

```
sed -r -e '/^line2/ s/(.*)/# \1 #/' file
```

Comment: The `#` was just an example. Ideally I want to run multiple commands like `a TEXT` and `i TEXT` and `s///` and `d`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple commands, just replace lines starting with `line2`:

```
sed "s/^line2.*/# & #/" file
```

Comment: I want to do more than just `s///`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^line2/!b;s/^/.../;s/$/.../' file
```

Here the regexp is negated by using the `!` command and the `b` command by itself  branches to the end of all sed commands. Perhaps as easier example would be:

```
sed ' /^lines/bjumphere;bjumpthere;:jumphere;s/^/.../;s/$/.../;:jumpthere' file
```

Of course the above can also be written:

```
sed '/^line2/{s/^/.../;s/$/.../}' file
```

When writing one liners that end in a newline (such as `i`, `a`, `c`, `r`, `R`, `w` and `W` commands) and further commands are wanted, the `-e` option may be invoked for each part of the sed script, an example:

```
sed -e '/^line2/{i\a couple of lines\ninserted before "line2"' -e '}' file
```

Also could be written:

```
sed '/^line2/i\a couple of lines\ninserted before "line2"' file
```

if there are no subsequent sed commands to be executed, however if `line2` needed to be deleted too:

```
sed -e '/^line2/b;!i\a couple of lines\ninserted before "line2 then line2 deleted"' -e 'd' file
```

However a better way would be to use the `c` command.

```
sed '/^line2/c\a line changed and a line\nappended for "line2"' file
```