# Split and Process text file in sh

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a text file with comma (,) separator :

```
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=3_6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=4_60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=3_5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=1_59,8401
```

I would like to get the output :

```
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,4,60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,1,59,8401
```

So for each line I flattened field " tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=3_6 " in " 3,6" for example.

Would you have any idea on how I could do this?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## sed

*awk* has already been covered by other answers. Here is an alternative using *sed*:

`$ sed -E -e 's/[^,]+;[^=]+=//' -e 's/_/,/' file`

#### Explanation

- `sed -E` in order to use *Extended regular expressions*.
- `sed -e` executes a sed script. Remember to enclose the sed scripts in single-quotes (`'`), to stop the shell from expanding it. We will need to execute two scripts.
- `s/[^,]+;[^=]+=//` The first of the two scripts. Strips away the string we don't want (*tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=*):

  - Substitute (`s/`)
  - one or more characters that are not the comma (`[^,]+`)
  - followed by a single semicolon (`;`)
  - followed by one or more characters that are not the equals sign (`[^=]+`)
  - followed by a single equals sign (`=`)
  - with nothing, i.e. delete the matched string (`//`).
- `s/_/,/` The second of the two scripts. Replaces the underscore (`_`) between the two numbers with a comma (`,`):

  - Subsitute (`s/`)
  - a single underscore (`_`)
  - with a comma (`/,/`).

---

#### Alternatives

Some more shell alternatives without awk:

- **`sed` piping**
  The two *sed* scripts could also have been used with a pipe:
  `$ sed -E 's/[^,]+;[^=]+=//' file | sed 's/_/,/'`.
  This would be less efficient, but if speed is no concern, some people may find it easier to understand. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands) for details.
- **`sed` + `tr`**
  The second part of the pipe above can be exchanged with a simple `tr` command:
  `$ sed -E 's/[^,]+;[^=]+=//' file | tr '_' ','`.
- **`tr` + `cut`**
  We can also do without sed:
  `$ tr '=_' ',' < file | cut -d, -f 1-5,7-9`
  Here, we first replace the `=` and the `_` with `,` using `tr`, in order to have our fields separated by commas,
  and print all the fields except the 6th one with `cut` (`-d` denotes the delimiter which is `,`, and `-f` denotes the fields we want to print, i.e. all except the 6th).
- **`sed` group captioning**
  See also [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164069/split-and-process-text-file-in-sh/55165137#55165137) which uses sed's group captioning.

Comment: wrt `awk has already been covered by other answers` - so has sed, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55165137/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton you're right, I didn't see it when I initially started writing my answer. I've added a reference to it.

Answer (score 3):

For this data:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[,_=]";OFS=","}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$8,$9}' file
```

Output:

```
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,4,60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,1,59,8401
```

Explained:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
    FS="[,_=]"                    # use multiple chars as field separators
    OFS=","
}
{
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$8,$9
}' file
```

Comment: Your missing a field in the output. Instead `[,=_]` for the delimiter and `$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$8,$9` for the list of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, if I got it right you need to fetch lines which have string `tel:+33xxxxxxx` in it.

```
awk -F'[,_=]' 'BEGIN{OFS=","} /tel:\+33xxxxxxx/{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$8,$9}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you don't want to hard-code(these values could be anywhere in Input_file) the field numbers then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
match($0,/^[0-9]+\,tel:\+33xxxxxxx\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+\,[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  match($0,/kn-corp-groups=[0-9]+_[0-9]+\,[0-9]+/)
  val1=substr($0,RSTART+15,RLENGTH-15)
  sub("_",",",val1)
  print val,val1
  val=val1=""
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,4,60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,1,59,8401
```

Comment: @Shakile, Could you please check and let me know if this solution is helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

use `gawk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } NF {$(NF-1) = gensub(/.*=(.*)_/, "\\1,", 1, $(NF-1))}1' file
```

Here we just need to process the next to the last column `$(NF-1)` with `gensub()` and `NF` as a condition to skip EMPTY lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/[^,]*;[^,]*\([0-9]*\)_/\1,/' file
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,4,60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,1,59,8401
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl regex

```
perl -pe ' s/(.*)(tel:.*=)(.*)_(.*)/$1$3,$4/ ' file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat shakile.txt
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=3_6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=4_60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=3_5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,tel:+33xxxxxxx;kn-corp-groups=1_59,8401

$ perl -pe ' s/(.*)(tel:.*=)(.*)_(.*)/$1$3,$4/ ' shakile.txt
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,4,60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,1,59,8401

$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub(/_/,",")}{print (substr($0, 1,29) substr($0, 60))}' file

60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,6,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,4,60,8401
60,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,0,3,5,8401
61,tel:+33xxxxxxx,840191,1,1,1,59,8401
```