# Using IFS to split a String into an Array with delimiter in bash

Tags: linux, bash, centos, debian

I have a variable `data="password: password@123, url: url@123, username: user@123"`.
I am trying to split this using the delimiter comma(`,`). I came up with the following script and it works well in CentOS Linux. But the same does not work in Debian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch).

```sh
IFS=, read -a array <<< $data
echo ${array[1]}
echo ${array[2]}
echo ${array[3]}
```

Gives the output (CentOS Linux):

```
password: password@123
url: url@123
username: user@123
```

But for Debian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch) the output is empty. Kindly help me with it!

---

**EDIT:**
The value for data is obtained from a JSON response.

```
data=$(vault kv get -format=json myapp/database | jq '.data' | sed '0,/{/ s/{//' | sed -r 's/(.*)}/\1 /' | sed s/\"//g)
echo $data
password: password@123, url: url@123, username: user@123
```

The response of `vault kv get -format=json myapp/database`:

```
{
  "request_id": "5eee87f9-16dc-fd62-e249-8737a6cd7041",
  "lease_id": "",
  "lease_duration": 2764800,
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
    "password": "password@123",
    "url": "url@123",
    "username": "user@123"
  },
  "warnings": null
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**: This script works in both Centos and Ubuntu

```
data=$(vault kv get -format=json myapp/database | jq '.data')
data=$(echo $data | sed 's/ //g' | sed '0,/{/ s/{//' | sed -r 's/(.*)}/\1 /' | sed 's/\"//g')
IFS=, read -a array <<< $data
```

Comment: Try quoting your variables, `data="password: password@123, url: url@123, username: user@123"; IFS=, read -a array <<< "$data"; declare -p array` Or `printf '%s\n' "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}" "${array[2]}"`

Comment: Also https://www.shellcheck.net is a good resource for shell scripts.

Comment: I can't repro; I get the same result on both platforms (CentOS 8.3.2011); the array element `${array[2]}` is empty, but that's because you are using the wrong indices (the first element is in `${array[0]}`). See https://pastebin.com/KyDSCfYk

Comment: If that's not it, could you still [edit] to include the output from running the script with `bash -x` on Debian?

Comment: As an aside, `jq -r ' .data | to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value)"'` avoids the fugly `sed` postprocessing. I doubt you really particularly want to split on commas; this produces newline-delimited output.

Comment: @tripleee The script works fine in CentOS but not on Ubuntu Debian. Any thought on it?

Comment: You mean other than [what I already suggested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480611/using-ifs-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-with-delimiter-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment119273564_67480611)

Comment: Put a newline at the end of ``$data``. `read -a array <<< "$data"$'\n'`.

Comment: @Darkman No need and no use; `read` ignores it anyway.

Comment: @tripleee At least not for my ``read``. Without a newline character, ``read`` seems to ignore the line.

Comment: @B.Akshay Instead of using ``read``, why not just using **for loop**. `IFS=, local i=1; for what in $data; do case $i in 1) echo '1='"$what" ;; 2) echo '2='"$what" ;; esac; i=$((i + 1)); done`

Comment: ... or then hack the `jq` output to provide it in a more useful format. With Bash 5 you could have it print the assignment syntax for an associative array.

Comment: @Darkman No repro; I wonder how exactly you are testing that? https://ideone.com/graOFa

Comment: You really should combine your multiple `sed` invocations. `sed` is a scripting language; it is not limited to a single command per invocation. (But then even better would be to clean up your `jq` so you don't need `sed` at all.)

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question does not reproduce the problem. The question was rightfully closed, and we still are not sure why the code you posted was not working.

However, the proper fix is probably to refactor your `jq` command line to output the results you want, instead of try to fix it up with a sequence of messy `sed` commands.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
vault kv get -format=json myapp/database |
jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"')" |
while IFS= read -r key value; do
    printf -v "$key" %s "$value"
done
```

Perhaps a better design is to read these into an associative array, provided your Bash is new enough (5+).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -A config
vault kv get -format=json myapp/database |
jq -r '.data | to_entries[] | "\(.key) \(.value)"')" |
while IFS= read -r key value; do
    config["$key"]="$value"
done
```

Perhaps there are ways to get `vault kv get` to format its output in a format which is more suitable for using in a shell script, too.

(Tangentially, *nearly* anything which looks like `sed 's/a/b/' | sed 's/x/y/g'` is better refactored into `sed 's/a/b/;s/x/y/g'`.  See also [Combining two sed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands.))

Comment: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/kv/get suggests that its default output format is probably more suitable for what you are trying to do. JSON is fine if your consumer understands JSON, but Bash doesn't, so you are just complicating things.