# How to replace text in json using bash

Tags: json, bash

I am trying to replace *qa_test_services* by *test_services* using bash in JSON file, could someone please help me with this ? thanks

**JSON file - variables.json**

```
{
    "variable": {
        "qa_test_services": {
            "default": {
                "prod-test-1": {
                    "position": 0,
                    "service_name": "test-1-service"
                },
                "prod-test-2": {
                    "position": 1,
                    "service_name": "test-2-service"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**bash - script**

```
test_json="variables.json"
actual_text="qa_test_services"
replace_text="test_services"

SEARCH_LINE=`cat $test_json | grep $actual_text | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/://g' | sed 's/{//g' | sed -e 's/  */ /g'`
echo $SEARCH_LINE
```

Comment: See also [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep), and [Combining two `sed` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands)

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid the temptation to edit json with line oriented tools. Like xml, It will not always be nicely formatted. Try using jq; it's like sed for json.

```sh
jq -f filter.jq variables.json
```

filter.jq

```
.variable |= with_entries(
    if .key == "qa_test_services" then
        .key = "test_services"
    else
        .
    end)
```

output

```json
{
  "variable": {
    "test_services": {
      "default": {
        "prod-test-1": {
          "position": 0,
          "service_name": "test-1-service"
        },
        "prod-test-2": {
          "position": 1,
          "service_name": "test-2-service"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

using bash variables

```sh
jq ".variable |= with_entries(
    if .key == \"$actual_text\" then
        .key = \"$replace_text\"
    else
        .
    end)" $test_json
```

Comment: Rather than 'nicely', I would say 'correctly formatted and escaped'! +1

Answer (score 1):

If the string you want to replace is exactly that, you could just use this simple `sed` command:

```
$ sed 's/qa_test_services/test_services/' variables.json
{
  "variable": {
    "test_services": {
      "default": {
        "prod-test-1": {
          "position": 0,
          "service_name": "test-1-service"
        },
        "prod-test-2": {
          "position": 1,
          "service_name": "test-2-service"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're happy with the result you can either pipe the output to a different file:

```
sed 's/qa_test_services/test_services/' variables.json > replaced.json
```

Or instruct `sed` to modify the file in-place:

```
sed -i .backup 's/qa_test_services/test_services/' variables.json
```

Where `.backup` is the extension that `sed` should use for the backup file it creates.

Comment: This works locally but fails if I try in azure devops pipeline

Answer (score 0):

This is another example using escape chars as I needed this, thought it would help someone else!

```
sed 's/\/sounds/\/apps\/soundboard\/sounds/' soundboard.json > test_json_new
```