# How to fix memory error while importing a very large csv file to mongodb in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, mongodb, csv

Given below is the code for importing a pipe delimited csv file to monogdb.

```
import csv
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
client = MongoClient(url)
db = client.Office
customer = db.Customer
jsonArray = []

with open("Names.txt", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect='excel', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in csv_reader:
        jsonArray.append(row)
    jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=1, separators=(",", ":"))
    jsonfile = json.loads(jsonString)
    customer.insert_many(jsonfile)
```

Below is the error I get when running the above code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda Projects\Mongo Projects\Office Tool\csvtojson.py", line 16, in <module>
    jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=1, separators=(",", ":"))
  File "C:\Users\Predator\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\Predator\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
MemoryError
```

I if modify the code with some indents under the for loop. The MongoDB gets imported with the same data all over again without stopping.

```
import csv
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
client = MongoClient(url)
db = client.Office
customer = db.Customer
jsonArray = []

with open("Names.txt", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect='excel', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in csv_reader:
        jsonArray.append(row)
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=1, separators=(",", ":"))
        jsonfile = json.loads(jsonString)
        customer.insert_many(jsonfile)
```

Comment: Using [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) might be the better option. Note, `mongoimport` also accepts input from STDIN, you could convert lines in python and then print to STDIN instead of writing a separate file.

Comment: I don't know python but perhaps insert like `if (row % 1000 == 0) customer.insert_many(jsonfile)`, i.e. Insert documents in batches of 1000

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit this is the result
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda Projects\Mongo Projects\SDR Tool\csvtojson.py", line 18, in <module>
    if row % 1000 == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'dict' and 'int'
`

Comment: Can you add a small sample of the file format - just 3 or 4 lines

Comment: ^^ Plus a header row (if you have one)

Comment: @Belly Buster The problem comes exactly here because the header is different for each csv file. for example Registration No|Date of Birth|Profession etc changes to RegNo|DOB|Job in another csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory issue can be solved by inserting one record at a time.

```
import csv
import json

from pymongo import MongoClient

url_mongo = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
client = MongoClient(url_mongo)
db = client.Office
customer = db.Customer
jsonArray = []
file_txt = "Text.txt"
rowcount = 0
with open(file_txt, "r") as txt_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(txt_file, dialect="excel", delimiter="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in csv_reader:
        rowcount += 1
        jsonArray.append(row)
    for i in range(rowcount):
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray[i], indent=1, separators=(",", ":"))
        jsonfile = json.loads(jsonString)
        customer.insert_one(jsonfile)
print("Finished")
```

**Thank You All for Your Ideas**

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use pandas; it provides a ["chunked" mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) by setting a chunksize parameter which you can tweak depending on your memory limitations. `insert_many()` is also more efficient.

Plus the code become much simpler:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = "Names.txt"

with pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=1000, delimiter='|') as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        db.mycollection.insert_many(chunk.to_dict('records'))
```

If you post a file sample I can update to match.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Predator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 722, in _alert_malformed
    raise ParserError(msg)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 48 fields in line 117143, saw 49

Comment: Given Below is the code I used.
`with pd.read_csv(csv_file, chunksize=1000, delimiter='|', engine='python', encoding='latin-1', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) as reader: for chunk in reader:`

Comment: I can't really help more without seeing a file sample.

Comment: Also that error is pretty straightforward - you have 48 fields in your headers and a line with 49 entries.

Comment: This is because some text might have a coma inserted in between.

Comment: is it possible to make a chunksize=1000 in with this code `csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect='excel', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) as reader:`

Comment: If you set the delimiter to `|` a comma won't be an issue. You might have an extra `|` though.

Comment: I tried using the sed command and replaced all | with comma and the file was loaded without any errors.

Comment: This was my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708872/how-to-convert-pipe-delimited-to-csv-or-json/70710266?noredirect=1#comment125004652_70710266