# How to mv (rename) a file that stats with dash if we get the file from a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, echo, mv

I am trying to rename a file using the move (mv) command

```bash
$ls

-0
-1
-2
```

to

```bash
000.json
001.json
002.json
```

the code I tried

```bash
for i in -*; do
  N=3
  echo mv -v -- "\"""$i""\"" "$(echo "$i" | sed -r ":r;s/\b[0-9]{1,$((N - 1))}\b/0&/g;tr" | sed "s/-//" | sed "s/$/.json/")"
  mv -v -- "\"""$i""\"" "$(echo "$i" | sed -r ":r;s/\b[0-9]{1,$((N - 1))}\b/0&/g;tr" | sed "s/-//" | sed "s/$/.json/")"
done
```

this code outputs

```
mv -v -- "-0" 000.json
mv: cannot stat '"-0"': No such file or directory
mv -v -- "-1" 001.json
mv: cannot stat '"-1"': No such file or directory
mv -v -- "-2" 002.json
mv: cannot stat '"-2"': No such file or directory
```

If I try to execute
`mv -v -- "-0" 000.json`
this works. but when I try to do it with `mv -v -- "\"""$i""\"" "$(echo "$i" | sed -r ":r;s/\b[0-9]{1,$((N - 1))}\b/0&/g;tr" | sed "s/-//" | sed "s/$/.json/")"`. It won't work.

Can anybody help me fixing `mv -v -- "\"""$i""\"" ...` this part of command Where in `"\"""$i""\""` I am just trying to add quotes? So It give `No such file or directory`.

Comment: The solution is the same as when the value does not come from a variable. Probably the easiest way to fix your code is to use `for i in ./-*`

Comment: More quotes do nothing to solve this problem, because the problem is not related to quoting. Quotes simply tell _the shell_ to not perform various changes to the string, but the problem here is not that the shell passes the wrong value, it's that the value has a special meaning to `mv`

Comment: how can this help `for i in ./-*` . it still gives `mv: cannot stat '"./-2"': No such file or directory
`

Comment: You don't have to use external commands such as `sed` for this task. This should do the trick at once: `for f in -[0-9]*; do echo mv -- "$f" "$(printf '%03d.json' "${f:1}")"; done`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin thx a lot. your comment worked. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Because you have the extra quotes in the body of the loop. You just want `mv -v "$i" "00${i#-}.json"` inside the loop, though that won't work if you have more than nine files.

Comment: Tangentially, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-two-sed-commands

Comment: Closed questions cannot receive answers. This is a common duplicate which has been answered dozens or hundreds of times before.

Comment: This works... `ls | sed -E 's/-([0-9]+)/mv .\/-\1 0\1.json/g' | bash`

Answer (score 1):

##### Basically, to avoid errors on files starting with a dash `-`, use:

```
command -- *
command ./*
```

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

```
rename -n 's/-(\d+)/sprintf("%.3d%s", $1, ".json")/e' ./*
rename(-0, 000.json)
rename(-1, 001.json)
rename(-2, 002.json)
```